# Firefox extension for one-click SSL override?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, ssl

When I visit a site with an invalid SSL certificate, I get a message saying "This connection is untrusted". If I want to visit it nevertheless, I have to click "I understand the risks", **uncheck** "Permanently store this exception" and click "Confirm Security Exception".

[image: Add Security Exception dialog]

I'd like to have a way to temporarily ignore the certificate with *one* click. This seems like something there should be an extension for, but I couldn't find any. Can someone help me out?

Ideally, the override should be really temporary - so it should last as long as the tab is open, or I am using that domain, but *not* until I restart the browser (like it does by default). Also, I'd like a temporary override, not an exception. If you add an exception, Firefox shows in the address bar that everything is OK. It should still visually warn that something's wrong. But this are just minor wishes, what I really want most is the one click behavior.

(A bit about my motivation: The default way to add an excaption is a lot of hassle if I just want some quick information from that site. I know that the certificate is invalid and I don't care because 1) I won't enter sensitive information or 2) it is on our intranet and uses custom certificates, or I even set it up myself.

It's also dangerous because I could easily miss-click the "Permanently store" checkbox and make the exception permanent. Also, when I do it very quickly, and uncheck the box right after the window opens, it sometimes gets checked immediately again (probably because it is initialised after the window is shown. I think this bug is fixed in recent versions, or is invisible on sufficiently fast PCs. On my work PC, it happens every now and then though.).)

Answer (score 1):

The extension is called [MitM Me](https://addons.mozilla.org/addon/mitm-me/) and allows bypassing the certificate error with one click. Obviously, when you use it you give away all the security that SSL is supposed to provide. In other words, **not recommended** to use other than in some exceptional scenarios. And you should **never** trust websites that you "enabled" this way.

Note that a permanent exception is significantly **more** secure when dealing with self-signed certificates. This way you will know that a website that you visit today is the same one that you visited yesterday - it still uses the certificate you permanently allowed. Should this certificate change you will get a warning again, you will know then that something wrong is going on.